# What VST works well with Pro Tools?

Tags: pro-tools, daw, vst

I'm trying to get a DAW VST combo where I can make music with midi that may use instruments like a rock orchestra I guess. I tried using Magix Music Maker but the quality of the instruments is not good. I have heard good reviews of pro-tools DAW (other recommendations for what I'm trying to do are cool), but VSTs would be needed with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protools only works with AAX format plugins and does not support VST plugins at all. You may be able to purchase an adapter that will allow this, but reports are variable as to how well this works. Recommend using another DAW that directly supports VST.

Comment: Great thanks, do you recommend a combination for creating orchestra and rock sounds?

Comment: If you are looking to build a sampled orchestral library, there are many to choose from. East West is a good place to start looking. There are also lots of drum machine/samples out there too. For rough sketching, Logic Pro X has a good drummer plugin built in, otherwise Superior drummer as a plugin. For anything else Rock, you'll need to record it.

Comment: Yes I've had to record a guitar because the virtual one sounded really bad. Bass guitar is ok though. Thanks